# Spring & Tiles - Get rid of tiles.xml

Tags: spring, configuration, tiles

I have a Tiles template where each page provides a title, some stuff to add in the `<head>`, stuff to put in some concrete `<div>`, and stuff to append to `<body>` after everything else.

Most of those things are very small since the page is rendered with JS.

How can I get rid of `tiles.xml` or make it more manageable?

I don't want each of the pages to require 3 files:

```
<definition name="my_page" template="/template.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="My Title" />
    <put-attribute name="head" value="/tiles/my-head.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/tiles/my-page.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body-append" value="/tiles/my-append.jsp" />
</definition>
```

And I don't want to put content of all pages in tiles.xml.

Ideally, it would simply redirect my_page to `/my_page.jsp` which would import and fill the template by itself.

I'm talking about a Spring app with `TilesView`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the tiles JSP tags directly in your JSP. You don't have to use definitions if you don't want to.

**In your my_page.jsp:**

```
<tiles:insertTemplate template="/template.jsp" flush="true">
<tiles:putAttribute name="title" value="My Title" />
<tiles:putAttribute name="head" value="/tiles/my-head.jsp" />
... etc
</tiles:insertTemplate>
```

See http://tiles.apache.org/framework/tiles-jsp/tlddoc/index.html